# Is it possible to have a chemfig compound in a figure caption?

Tags: subcaption, chemfig

I am trying to insert a `\chemfig` compound in my figure caption but am unable to compile and I'm not sure why.  I'm getting a generic `\chemfig` error message in my log file.

Here is an example caption:

```
\caption{yada yada yada \chemfig{H_2O} yada yada yada}
```

However, when I use the `\mathrm` call I am able to get the compound to look correct.

```
\caption{yada yada yada $\mathrm{H_2O}$ yada yada yada}
```

Any ideas why?  Should I even bother, or just move on with `\mathrm`?

Comment: Is it just about linear molecules (e.g., H2O, C6H6) or complex structures (e.g., benzene rings)?

Comment: If you're just interested in chemical formulae as opposed to structural formulae, using the `chemformula`  or the `mhchem` package should be sufficient.

Comment: For me, it was just linear molecules, but I'm assuming that more complex structures could be added.  I just saw this was answered by adding a ```\protect``` before the ```\chemfig``` call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put a `\protect` in front of it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=10cm]{example-image-golden}
\caption{yada yada yada \protect\chemfig{H_2O} yada yada yada}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

See [`\protect` on latexref.xyz](https://latexref.xyz/_005cprotect.html#g_t_005cprotect) for more.

Comment: Awesome! Worked perfectly.